# Python polymorphism trouble

Tags: python

In python, I defined a class 'number'. Now I wish to define a function named 'number' too. (Just like 'int' or 'str' are classes as well as you can use them as functions ('int()' , 'str()') for type conversion). How can I do the same with (my class and function) 'number'?

[Would it be correct to call this as polymorphism?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class number(object):
    def __init__(self, value)
        self.val = value # or something like that

n = number(2.3)
```

`int()` and `str()` are *not* functions, they are type constructors. So you need to make your own <s>constructor</s> initializer.

Comment: Your own **initializer**, not constructor. The difference is... subtle, and not terribly important until you dig a little deeper.

Answer (score 1):

what you want are callables. Look at [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) for more.